# Getting the UIButton that was double-tapped from UIGestureRecognizer's action method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer, sender

I wrote a fairly long action method connected to several `UIButton`s, and now I've realised I would like to have something different happen if I tap one of the buttons twice. So I am setting up two gesture recognizers:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapTwice:)];


tapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice];

[self.mybutton addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
[self.mybutton addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];
```

then, I implement the methods:

```
- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
   //Do what you were already doing
}


- (void)tapTwice:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{ 
  // Some new functionality
}
```

Now, I don't have a problem with the new functionality. Where I get stuck is trying to get the `tapOnce:` method to do what my button was already doing. I need to know which button was tapped, so I can't use this:

```
[myButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I also tried the old:

```
for (button in myArrayOfButtons){
    [button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

No luck either.

Then I went the way of actually creating a separate method for the implementation of my button, so what was:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

   //my functionality...
}
```

became:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self myMethodwithSender:sender];
}

-(void)myMethodwithSender: (id)sender{

    // my functionality
 }
```

So that worked in itself, but when I try to put the tap once and twice into play I get stuck. I tried putting my new method in the method for tap once:

```
- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

       [self myMethodwithSender:sender];
}
```

but of course there is no sender in this method so it doesn't work (right?)

Then I tried changing this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
```

to this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(myMethodwithSender:)];
```

Which doesn't work either. So I am not sure how to do this. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What do you mean "it's actually an array of buttons", and what does "No luck either" mean exactly? What is happening?

Comment: in my project there are many buttons and they are all hooked to this one method. Then, depending on the one you press (hence the importance of "sender") a different image appears and so on... when i try:     UIButton *button; for (button in self.allTheButtons){ [self myMethodwithSender:sender];} in the tapOnce method. I get the error "use of undeclared identifier sender.

Comment: In that case, Lou Franco's answer is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
   [self myMethodwithSender:sender];
}
```

If `myMethodWithSender` doesn't use sender, you can send nil.  If it needs it to be the button, `gesture.view` should be that button (if you attached the recognizer to the button)

Comment: I just tried gesture.view and it works but the app slows down noticeably (an image appears when you click the buttons and it's appearing with a delay?)

Comment: You can only know that a second tap isn't coming if you wait a little for it.  The single tap can't fire until that timeout is reached.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Since we are at it, any idea why     UIButton *button;
    for (button in self.allTheButtons){
        [button addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
        [button addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];} would not be working?

Comment: You need a new gesture recognizer object for each button.